# How can I further reduce my MP size $\alpha$ test given a random sample from a shifted exponential distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, neyman-pearson-lemma

Let $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ be a random sample from $f(x|\theta)=e^{-(x-\theta)},x>\theta,$ where $\theta$ is an unknown real number. Find an MP size $\alpha$ test for $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ v. $H_1:\theta=\theta_1$. Let $\theta_0 < \theta_1$ both be known.

**My work:**

By Neyman-Pearson Lemma, we have the MP test as $\phi(X)=1,\frac{f(\mathbf{x}|\theta_1)}{f(\mathbf{x}|\theta_0)}>k$.

$\frac{f(\mathbf{x}|\theta_1)}{f(\mathbf{x}|\theta_0)}=\frac{I_{(\theta_1,\infty)}(x_{(1)})}{I_{(\theta_0,\infty)}(x_{(1)})}exp[-\sum^n_{i=1}x_i+\sum^n_{i=1}x_i]exp[n(\theta_1-\theta_0)]>k$

$=\frac{I_{(\theta_1,\infty)}(x_{(1)})}{I_{(\theta_0,\infty)}(x_{(1)})}>k'$, since $\theta_1 > \theta_0$.

Thus the MP level $\alpha$ test is: $\phi(X)=1,\frac{I_{(\theta_1,\infty)}(x_{(1)})}{I_{(\theta_0,\infty)}(x_{(1)})}>k'$

Is there a way to further reduce this MP test? I have not seen any examples where there is a constant $k'$ in the test statement.

Comment: Of course you have to express the critical region in terms of $X_{(1)}$ only.

Comment: @StubbornAtom So $\phi(X)=I_{(\theta_1,\infty)}>I_{(\theta_0,\infty)}$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2904134/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thank you - I just assumed that I would need to divide by $e^{n(\theta_1-\theta_0)}$ on your 6th inline equation. How do you decide what terms to divide over to the constant $k$ and which terms to keep?

Comment: I was just simplifying the likelihood ratio. Here it does not matter if you take out the $e^{n(\theta_1-\theta_0)}$ term because it is a positive constant not depending on $x_{(1)}$. The main work is to study the nature of the ratio as a function of the sufficient statistic $x_{(1)}$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I see. So we could alternatively have $\lambda(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=1, $if $ x_{(1)}>\theta_1$, which is still a non-decreasing function of $x_{(1)}$, so $\lambda(x_1,\cdots,x_n)>k \implies x_{(1)}>c$, which returns the same answer. Great- thank you for your help!

Comment: That constant term is included in $\lambda$. You can take it out only after you say $\lambda>k$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you again @StubbornAtom

Comment: Please provide an answer below if you wish to keep the question.